# XSLT Markup help

Tags: data-view-web-part, content-query-web-part, xslt

Any xsl examples on how to achieve this html markup

```
<div id="rotate">
    <ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
    <div>First content</div>
    <div>Second content</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Anything can be done by simply modifying the templates in the DVWP.  It's unclear here what your source data is like so it'll be difficult to tell you how exactly.

Comment: Hi PirateEric, my datasource data will be a custom list.